# Java code for parsing a complex XML file

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Below is a program written to parse the accompanying XML file.

Problem: There are two lane-IDs, but the output of my code keeps outputting only one. I expect the output to be:

> Current Element: detector-report
>   Detector ID : I-74 NB from 12th Ave to 7th Ave
>   Status : operational
>   
>   Lane-ID : 1
>   Lane - ID: 2

The current code still outputs 1 on the last line.

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FinalTrial {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("workFile_09282014 22-10-34c.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("detector-report");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    System.out.println("Detector ID : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("detector-id").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Status : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("status").item(0).getTextContent());
                    NodeList lanes = eElement.getElementsByTagName("lane");
                    System.out.println(lanes.getLength());
                    for (int j = 0; j<lanes.getLength(); j++) {
                         Element lane = (Element) lanes.item(0);
                         System.out.println("Lane-ID : " + lane.getElementsByTagName("lane-id").item(0).getTextContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the accompanying XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trafficDetectorData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://www.dummy-temp-address" xmlns:lrms="http://www.dummy-lrms-address" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dummy-temp-address C:\temp\test\Detectors.xsd">
    <detector-report>
      <detector-id>I-74 NB from Ave of the Cities t</detector-id>
      <status>operational</status>
        <lane>
          <lane-id>1</lane-id>
          <count>1</count>
          <volume>1</volume>
          <occupancy>0</occupancy>
          <speed>122</speed>
          <classes>
            <class>
              <class-id>Small</class-id>
              <count>1</count>
              <volume>1</volume>
            </class>
            <class>
              <class-id>Medium</class-id>
            </class>
            <class>
              <class-id>Large</class-id>
            </class>
          </classes>
        </lane>
        <lane>
          <lane-id>2</lane-id>
          <occupancy>0</occupancy>
          <speed>137</speed>
          <classes>
            <class>
              <class-id>Small</class-id>
            </class>
            <class>
              <class-id>Medium</class-id>
            </class>
            <class>
              <class-id>Large</class-id>
            </class>
          </classes>
        </lane>
    </detector-report>
    <detector-report>
      <detector-id>I-74 NB from 12th Ave to 7th Ave</detector-id>
      <status>operational</status>
        <lane>
          <lane-id>1</lane-id>
          <count>3</count>
          <volume>3</volume>
          <occupancy>3</occupancy>
          <speed>100</speed>
          <classes>
            <class>
              <class-id>Small</class-id>
              <count>3</count>
              <volume>3</volume>
            </class>
            <class>
              <class-id>Medium</class-id>
            </class>
            <class>
              <class-id>Large</class-id>
            </class>
          </classes>
        </lane>
        <lane>
          <lane-id>2</lane-id>
          <count>4</count>
          <volume>4</volume>
          <occupancy>3</occupancy>
          <speed>116</speed>
          <classes>
            <class>
              <class-id>Small</class-id>
              <count>4</count>
              <volume>4</volume>
            </class>
            <class>
              <class-id>Medium</class-id>
            </class>
            <class>
              <class-id>Large</class-id>
            </class>
          </classes>
        </lane>
    </detector-report>
</trafficDetectorData>
```

Comment: In order to get an answer, you must first ask a question.

Comment: did you try to read jaxb, dom objects and sax objects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try to apply this tutorial to your file, if you faced any problem you can reply with it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Comment: and this one using dom http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html

Comment: `"The structure confuses me."` -- consider telling us what is confusing about it since to most of us, it looks like any other plain vanilla XML file. It is difficult to help you without your giving us specific information about what confuses you and without a specific answerable question.

Comment: And in fact this XML is easier than most to parse since except for the root element, none of its elements have any attributes.

Comment: I have edited the question above. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by *how do I add the values under lanes and classes*? In what way do you want to add them? What is the problem that you seen with the now provided java code? It is still unclear

Comment: UPDATED file and expected output

Answer (score 2):

I urge most developers to use established libraries for XML document handling, to avoid errors such as not properly escaping attribute values.

Java's built-in XML parsing library works very well (org.w3c.dom.Document, etc...).